# Shutdown and User button missing in panel

Tags: indicator, shutdown, panel

I faced with a problem after update,

I missed 2 buttons from above panel, System menu (including shutdown, suspend & …) and User (including log out & …) 
how can I restore them !?...

Comment: Can you upload a snap of the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure `indicator-session` is installed:

[image: Install via the software center]

or with

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-session
```

And then log out and back in again.

Comment: Thanx alot Mr.Castro :) It solved!

Answer (score 2):

If you like command line you can achieve the same thing with some commands

1. Hibernate :

   ```
   sudo pm-hibernate
   ```
2. Shutdown :

   ```
   sudo poweroff
   ```
3. Suspend :

   ```
   sudo pm-suspend
   ```

You can always use the command line reverse search (CTRL + R) and feed it some chars to execute the commands faster.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Xubuntu or using Xfce as desktop manager, there is no need to install `indicator-session` -- it will bring lots of extra packages to your desktop.

Instead add the Xfce plugin to the panel:

- right-click on the panel, then select **Panel** >
  **Panel Preferences...**
- select **Items** tab
- click on the **[+]** icon button
- look for "**Action Buttons**" and select it, then click **Add** button
- click **Close** button to finish

When you add "**Action Buttons**" to the panel, your username will immediately appear on the panel. Click on your username to see the actions (**Lock Screen**, **Switch User**, **Suspend**, **Shut Down**, **Log Out...**), which are available in the drop-down menu.

Works for me on Xubuntu 15.10 (fresh install).

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands to restore the defaults of your panel.

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Ubuntu 14.04 and lost user menu (Power Off, Log Out) and clock gadget in the classic GNOME panel bar after an update. Recently I upgarded to 16.04, the issues were still there. After executed

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

to go back classic GNOME panel. I was able to press **Alt+RightClick** or **Super+Alt+RightClick**  to bring up context menu

[image]

Click Add to Panel...

[image]

Scroll down

[image]

Pick desired items, e.g. User menu, Clock, etc. and click Add. Those items will be added to panel bar. BTW, mouse over on an item, press **Alt+RightClick**, popup menu **Move** or **Remove From Panel** will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get back the shut down-button in a few seconds is this:

a right mouse click on the task bar at the bottom, 2 options will appear, >preferences<, and >about<. Choose >preferences<, then >applets<, then the red circled >shut down<-button - just scoll down a bit to find it -, and confirm. That's it! Next time you reboot the original button or buttons will all be there again, instead of the red one, which you can reinstall each time again whenever you should need it.

But don't confuse it with the green circled >logout<, or the also red circled >quit-logout applet<.

You may also install the nice wheather applet, or terminal-applet on the way!