# Why can't I shut down after installing ubuntu-desktop from minimal CD?

Tags: unity

Because my CD drive just couldn't burn the 707 MiB ISO, I:

- installed Ubuntu from the Minimal CD and
- then added the GUI via `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`

Now my system boots to the Ubuntu's Unity desktop all fine, but the menu bar at the top is missing the shutdown button and notification area.

I couldn't find anything obvious amongst the recommended packages, so what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Comment: Try it once.. : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` then `ok` .

Comment: No change. I believe LightDM is working because the login screen does appear.

Comment: It would be good if you attach an image link to your question. It would help others to get your problem and solve it easily..

Comment: Okay, done. Notice the absence of the network manager, clock and shutdown symbols at the upper right.

Comment: Okay, the missing clock seems to be because indicator-datetime was one of the recommended packages that I didn't install. Hope I find the package for the shutdown thingy, too ;)

Comment: Have you tried updating?

Answer (score 1):

Missing power button indicator:

Solution for me after `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` was:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-session
```

Thanks to [Shutdown and User button missing in panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201263/shutdown-and-user-button-missing-in-panel)

---

Answer (score 0):

To install missing packages do this:

- Install the full Ubuntu desktop environment.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Install only install the packages you really need.(xorg xterm gdm menu)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop + only the packages you need for example menu
  ```

  Note: you can look at available packages with this command:

  ```
  apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- The really minimalistic way

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xorg xterm gdm menu gksu synaptic --no-install-recommends
  sudo apt-get install gnome-session gnome-panel metacity gnome-terminal --no-install-recommends
  ```

Comment: So, in short, you suspect I'm missing one of the recommended packages. That's what I suspect, too. I'd prefer to just add the missing package, though, instead of adding everything there is to my system.

Comment: hope the edited answer helps