# Where is the "logout" option in the Applications menu of gnome shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, logout

Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

I have been using this desktop for a week but till now I can not find where "logout" option is in the Applications menu. So my question is:

(1) Is this gnome shell, to be more specific, gnome 2's shell? Or is it called unity because the tip says "Get help with Unity"?

(2) Is there any "logout" menu item in the Applications menu (or any part of the screen) of this shell? If yes, where is it, or how to make it appear in the Applications menu?

Thanks a lot.

PS: This shell is obtained by the following commands:

```
metacity &
gnome-settings-daemon &
gnome-panel &
```

Comment: No, this is not GNOME Shell. This looks like GNOME 2.

Comment: and in gnome 2 there should be THREE option at the top; the 3rd named "System" having amongst others the shutdown option.

Comment: @muru: I tried answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/201263/shutdown-and-user-button-missing-in-panel. Doesn't work. PS: some answers there are just kidding us. For example, "a right mouse click on the task bar at the bottom, 2 options will appear", but nothing appears.

Comment: @user280121 Then something is seriously wrong, because those options should appear. What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @muru: 14.04 LTS. I think the ubuntu may missing some packages. If these missing packages are installed then the problem should be solved. But I don't know what are missing.

Comment: OH! might be permissions: if this is NOT the admin "system" might be disabled. Normal user is not allowed to shutdown by default!

Comment: @Rinzwind: I am the admin.

Comment: This must be the crippled panel from GNOME3 then. Did you install `gnome-session-flashback`? If not, install it (`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback` and relogin. Choose Flashback or Classic at the login screen.

Comment: @muru: I have already installed `gnome-session-flashback`. I'm afraid the key lies in the commands to obtain the gnome panel (I just realized that this is called GNOME Panel, the shell for GNOME 2, while GNOME Shell is the shell for GNOME 3). I may missing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it must be under System menu or you can type the command sudo shutdown -h over terminal if you would prefer to use terminal.